# MongoDB update inside array of object of array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Test Data:-

```
professor:{
 name:"temp1",
 department:[
 {name:"pro1",
 review:[
 {paper:"paper1",status:"review",paperid:"1"}
 ]}]}
```

I want to update the status "review" to "finish".
For to search I use :

```
 {
department: {
                $elemMatch: {
                  review: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                      paperid: id
                    }
                  }
                }
          }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all your documents where the status is `review` use:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  {$set: {"professor.department.$[].review.$[r].status": "finish"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"r.status": "review"}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3NxlU4Z1p8S)

If you want to update only where the `department.name` is `pro1` use:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  {$set: {"professor.department.$[d].review.$[r].status": "finish"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"d.name": "pro1"}, {"r.status": "review"}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example - department](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9L_lXs72hc_)

Answer (score 0):

by specify paperid

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {},
    {
        $set: { "professor.department.$[].review.$[r].status": 'finish' }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{ "r.paperid": '1' }]
    }
)
```